# how to group by and filter a dataframe based on different conditions for each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have the following data frame:

```
user_id var  gp         95_q
147     1   -75.19  529.3280
20395   2   -109.11 609.0675
32035   2   36.00   609.0675
33725   2   120.98  609.0675
47808   1   -17.89  529.3280
48633   1   -19.49  529.3280
110330  1   800     529.3280
117277  2   271.80  609.0675
1122081 2   7123.78 609.0675
129120  2   21.00   609.0675
131222  2   -4.95   609.0675
131480  1   18.58   529.3280
```

i need to create a new dataframe where for each group( var=1 and var=2) rows where gp is more that 95_q are filtered, as you can see 95_q is different for each group.

i took the following approach:

```
df.groupby('var').filter(lambda x: (x['gross_profit'] > x['95_q']))
```

but it returns the following error:

```
filter function returned a Series, but expected a scalar bool
```

when i convert the code to :

```
df.groupby('var').filter(lambda x: (x['gross_profit'] > x['95_q']).any())
```

i still get a dataframe that still has values more than 95_q

Comment: If you've already calculated 95_q, then you don't need groups to do this.  Just use boolean indexing.  `df[df['gp'] < df['95_q']]`

Comment: you do not need `groupby`

Answer (score 0):

as @Scott Boston mentioned boolean indexing is enough:

```
  df[df['gp'] < df['95_q']]
```